# The property on entity type has not been added to the model or ignored

Tags: entity-framework

Why am I getting this error when executing?

```
dnx ef database update
```

The property 'RowValues' on entity type 'Models.Foo' has not been added to the model or ignored.

```
 public class Foo
 {
     public ICollection<int> RowValues { get; set; }
     public ICollection<int> ColValues { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: it not matching datatype you are passing integer value and make sure database also have datatype integer or conversion needed

Comment: also check the value is not null or the feild is primary key anf auto specification is marked to yes if yes it will never allows you to enter must make it no

Comment: also enable null values after changing it from non auto increament

Comment: I am using localdb.  I would expect int to map very easily to a column type.  I should also add that the same occurs with List<int> & List<Int32> & Int32[].  A property of just int works fine but not a collection of them for some reason.  EF7 does not seem to like this construct.

Comment: oh bunch of values use store procedure and study table type must google `TABLE TYPE` to insert multiple value like datatable or list

Comment: As recently as last month I was told via Twitter from one of the EF Developers on Github that for some reason ICollection of primatives is not supported by Entity Framework.  To make this work you have to wrap your int in another Class Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The EDM does not support collections of primitive data types

<sup>[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee382832(v=vs.100).aspx)</sup>

You have to do something like:

```cs
public class Value
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Value> RowValues { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Value> ColValues { get; set; }
}
```

(Don't forget the ID property...)